# Chrome - Detect browser close or tab close

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using following two listeners on my page when a user closes a tab or window in chrome, but they don't seem to work

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function (integer tabId, object removeInfo) {alert("Haooooo")});

chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function (integer windowId) {alert("Haooooo")});
```

But, the following function detects the window close or tab close, but gets triggered on refresh too. Has any one have a way to detect the browser/tab close only for Chrome. I am not looking for this to work in any other browser. Looking for a solution only in chrome

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {          
          var confirmationMessage = "See you later" ;
          (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
          return confirmationMessage;
}
);
```

Comment: Wait, are you making an extension or not?

Answer (score 24):

Your syntax is invalid. It should be

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabid, removed) {
 alert("tab closed")
})

chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(windowid) {
 alert("window closed")
})
```

However, these apis will not work on normal webpages, only in extensions.

Comment: thanks. Like you said, the apis dont work with normal pages, how to detect browser close/tab close in chrome. Can you please give some idea

Comment: @naga1990 you can't do this without making an extension. It's as simple as that. The JavaScript on your page is sandboxed and unaware of other tabs - outside of web workers. The only way I can think that could possibly work is catching the `onclose` event and then posting a message to a web worker.. But that would only work on pages you had a script on - so your own pages, or an extension.